# Does aws personalize support search engine?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does Amazon Personalize support capabilities within itself or does it need to be integrated with ElasticSearch or other search engines?

Or It's support third party search engine?

I'm new for the  "aws personalise" services.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. What do you mean by "support search engine"? For information about about the service see: [What Is Amazon Personalize?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/what-is-personalize.html)

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. Does Amazon Personalize support capabilities within itself or does it need to be integrated with ElasticSearch or other search engines?

Comment: It is the "back-end" that can provide a list of suggested matches. See: [AWS re:Invent 2018: NEW! Introducing Amazon Personalize: Real-time Personalization & Recommendations - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sexYAHHjxE)

Comment: Thanks to give suggestion.